# Datanucleus JDO Informix query not returning results

Tags: java, informix, jdo, datanucleus

I have implemented Datanucleus JDO 5.0.10 with Informix database. I do manage to get the PMF and my query is being compiled but no results are being returned.

I have tried to change the version of datanucleus but the error still comes up; upgrading and downgrading.

Here is the stack trace i get:

```
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Exception thrown while loading remaining rows of query at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOAdapter.getUserExceptionForException(JDOAdapter.java:670)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.closingConnection(ForwardQueryResult.java:310)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractQueryResult.disconnect(AbstractQueryResult.java:105)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.AbstractRDBMSQueryResult.disconnect(AbstractRDBMSQueryResult.java:248)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JDOQLQuery$2.managedConnectionPreClose(JDOQLQuery.java:734)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:519)
    at org.datanucleus.store.connection.AbstractManagedConnection.release(AbstractManagedConnection.java:83)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.release(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:353)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JDOQLQuery.performExecute(JDOQLQuery.java:809)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1926)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithArray(Query.java:1815)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeInternal(JDOQuery.java:431)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeWithArray(JDOQuery.java:318)
    at com.swanretail.server.service.LocalClientPM.execute(LocalClientPM.java:143)
    at com.swanretail.service.Context.execute(Context.java:408)
    at com.swanretail.service.QueryBuilder.execute(QueryBuilder.java:286)
    at com.swanretail.service.SystemService.getLicencedUsers(SystemService.java:1930)
    at com.swanretail.jdo.Main.main(Main.java:99)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Failed to read the result set : ResultSet not open, operation 'next' not permitted. Verify that autocommit is OFF
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOAdapter.getDataStoreExceptionForException(JDOAdapter.java:681)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.nextResultSetElement(ForwardQueryResult.java:238)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult$QueryResultIterator.next(ForwardQueryResult.java:416)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.processNumberOfResults(ForwardQueryResult.java:143)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.advanceToEndOfResultSet(ForwardQueryResult.java:171)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.closingConnection(ForwardQueryResult.java:298)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractQueryResult.disconnect(AbstractQueryResult.java:105)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.AbstractRDBMSQueryResult.disconnect(AbstractRDBMSQueryResult.java:248)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JDOQLQuery$2.managedConnectionPreClose(JDOQLQuery.java:734)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:519)
    at org.datanucleus.store.connection.AbstractManagedConnection.release(AbstractManagedConnection.java:83)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.release(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:353)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JDOQLQuery.performExecute(JDOQLQuery.java:809)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1926)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithArray(Query.java:1815)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeInternal(JDOQuery.java:431)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeWithArray(JDOQuery.java:318)
    at com.swanretail.server.service.LocalClientPM.execute(LocalClientPM.java:143)
    at com.swanretail.service.Context.execute(Context.java:408)
    at com.swanretail.service.QueryBuilder.execute(QueryBuilder.java:286)
    at com.swanretail.service.SystemService.getLicencedUsers(SystemService.java:1930)
    at com.swanretail.jdo.Main.main(Main.java:99)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet not open, operation 'next' not permitted. Verify that autocommit is OFF
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildException(IfxErrMsg.java:480)
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:449)
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:400)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.next(IfxResultSet.java:442)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.nextResultSetElement(ForwardQueryResult.java:220)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult$QueryResultIterator.next(ForwardQueryResult.java:416)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.processNumberOfResults(ForwardQueryResult.java:143)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.advanceToEndOfResultSet(ForwardQueryResult.java:171)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.closingConnection(ForwardQueryResult.java:298)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractQueryResult.disconnect(AbstractQueryResult.java:105)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.AbstractRDBMSQueryResult.disconnect(AbstractRDBMSQueryResult.java:248)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JDOQLQuery$2.managedConnectionPreClose(JDOQLQuery.java:734)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:519)
    at org.datanucleus.store.connection.AbstractManagedConnection.release(AbstractManagedConnection.java:83)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.release(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:353)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JDOQLQuery.performExecute(JDOQLQuery.java:809)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1926)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithArray(Query.java:1815)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeInternal(JDOQuery.java:431)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeWithArray(JDOQuery.java:318)
    at com.swanretail.server.service.LocalClientPM.execute(LocalClientPM.java:143)
    at com.swanretail.service.Context.execute(Context.java:408)
    at com.swanretail.service.QueryBuilder.execute(QueryBuilder.java:286)
    at com.swanretail.service.SystemService.getLicencedUsers(SystemService.java:1930)
    at com.swanretail.jdo.Main.main(Main.java:99)
```

Comment: And have you verified that "autocommit" is OFF? or does it support autocommit being turned off ? I saw this page http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/datastores/datastores.html#informix  which references Informix and autocommit

Comment: We have set is_buff_log to 1. it was set to 0 initially